# How do I stop that the activity sliding in from happening?

Tags: android

When I call an activity through intent the activity slides in the device.
How do I stop that the activity sliding in from happening?
This is how I call the other Activity through intent

> Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
>
> startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use overridePendingAnimation(0,0); after startActivity () call

Answer (score 0):

create a style,

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

then in manifest set it as theme for activity or whole application.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
</activity>
```